# Problems running the npm install command to work with gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm-install

I am going to work with a project that is working with Gulp, but when I run the `npm install` command, I get the following errors.

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wofWI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command again with the flag `--force`

Answer (score 0):

try to run the command with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps`.

If it doesn't help, try to downgrade your nodejs version, probably a dependency issue.